# How can I adapt a Highcharts graph to a responsive view

Tags: highcharts

I have the code for the chart below which are some horizontal bars (see code). In the desktop version the horizontal bars are fine but in mobile versions I would prefer that the bars turn vertical so it fits the screen better. How can I have the bars to be displayed horizontal in Desktops but vertical in Mobile Devices? The idea is that not only the bars but the legends turn vertical as well. TIA

```js
//Grafica 1
$(function () {
    Highcharts.chart('grafica1', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ' '
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: {
              useHTML: true
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            title: {
                text: null,
            },
            labels: {
                    enabled: false,
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: { 
            enabled: false 
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '({point.y:.1f} Million tones)%'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Production',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'PACKAGING PAPERS<br>AND BOARDS',
                y: 49,
                color: '#005eb8',
            }, {
                name: 'CASE MATERIALS',
                y: 29.9,
                color: '#fff',
                borderWidth : 2,
                borderColor : '#005eb8'
            }, {
                name: 'OTHER PACKAGING & PAPER',
                y: 14.4,
                color: '#fff',
                borderWidth : 2,
                borderColor : '#005eb8'
            },{
                name: 'WRAPPINGS',
                y: 4.7,
                color: '#fff',
                borderWidth : 2,
                borderColor : '#005eb8'
            }]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="grafica1" class="chart1Slide2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `responsive` option to apply different chart options when some condition is fulfilled (e.g. if width is lower than 500px).

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/u81kfa4k/